# Static Variable showing as Null

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a class named Locator that I use to GeoLocate a user. There's a static method in that class called "locate()". This method then calls another method which sets a static variable called "loc" to  an instance of a LngLat class.

The issue I'm having is, when I call the locate method at Frame 1 on the scene, and then try to access the loc variable it shows as null... but when I trace the loc variable after it's set in the Locator class it shows as an object.

When I do this (at frame 1):

```
Locator.locate();
trace(Locator.loc.getCity());
```

null gets traced.

But when I have this in Frame 1:

```
Locator.locate();
```

and then trace the variable at the end of the static method in the Locator class it shows as a object and the city is traced as expected.

Any ideas?

P.S I did a bad job of explaining that, sorry.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure that the locate(); method does not take more than 1 frame?  (ex. 1/25 sec) Do you listen for any event.complete  or event.located ?? How does the code look inside the locate() function ?

Comment: Could you trace Locator.loc instead of Locator.loc.getCity(). The problem may be in getCity.

Comment: Paste your locate() and getCity() Please.

Comment: Hard to help without more source.

Answer (score 0):

> This answer is a best-guess using what *little* information you've provided.

Based on the context being capturing a location, it's likely that you're communicating with some server-side technology (i.e. a database full of coordinates).

To achieve this, you would have to be making use of `URLLoader`.

When you initialize an instance of `URLLoader` and attempt to collect information from a third party, the requested information will be received at a time which is *asynchronous*. This means that a function waiting to be called when flash receives the data you're after could be called anywhere in the near future, but not immediately.

Here's an experiment:

```
var data:Object = null;
var loader:URLLoader;

function test():void
{
    loader = new URLLoader();
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("https://projectavian.com/files/example.php");

    loader.load(request);
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, _done);
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _check);
}


function _done(e:Event):void
{
    data = e.target.data;
    trace(data);

    loader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, _done);
    stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _check);
}

function _check(e:Event):void
{
    trace(data);
}


test();
trace(data); // This will always be null even after all the work above.
```

If you run this, you'll notice that `data` is always initially `null`.

My *guess* is that your `Locator.locate()` needs some time to gather the information it needs, then assigns a value to whatever `Locator.loc.getCity()` returns.